# Accessing nested array properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

This may be extremely simple but I've not been able to figure out how to iterate over and access the properties in the following mix (I think) of arrays and nested objects:

```js
myFilters = {
    "color_Filter": [{
            "name": "BLUE",
            "count": 1,
            "dataId": "BLUE"
        },
        {
            "name": "Black",
            "count": 5,
            "dataId": "Black"
        },
        {
            "name": "Blue",
            "count": 14,
            "dataId": "Blue"
        }
    ],
    "size_Filter": [{
            "name": "10",
            "count": 16,
            "dataId": "10"
        },
        {
            "name": "12",
            "count": 16,
            "dataId": "12"
        }
    ]
}
```

What would the correct looping structure be here to pull out `name`, `count` etc from the above? The desired output is to output a string from the above with `color_Filter=BLUE,Black,Blue/size_Filter=10,12`

I've tried a few different approaches and none of them have been successful so far.

Comment: This is hard to understand. Please post the object in a JSON format. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(myFilters, null, 4))`.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I've updated the post to make it more readable, thanks @adiga

Comment: You could loop over `color_Filter` and then over `size_Filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `map` the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object and create a string for each key. Get the `name` from the value array using `map`. Then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array of strings with a `/`

```js
const myFilters = {color_Filter:[{name:"BLUE",count:1,dataId:"BLUE"},{name:"Black",count:5,dataId:"Black"},{name:"Blue",count:14,dataId:"Blue"}],size_Filter:[{name:"10",count:16,dataId:"10"},{name:"12",count:16,dataId:"12"}]};

const output = Object.entries(myFilters)
                     .map(([k,arr]) => `${k}=${arr.map(a => a.name)}`)
                     .join("/")

console.log(output)
```